# Concatenating a double and string to evaluate

Tags: java, function, arraylist, operators

I have two ArrayLists

```
[+, / , - ]
[12,8,5, 4]
```

My code:

```
        for(int i=0; i<ops.length; i++){
            String op = setOps.get(i);

            double numer1 = Double.parseDouble(setNumbers.get(i));
            double numer2 = Double.parseDouble(setNumbers.get(i+1));

            System.out.println(numer1+op+numer2);
        }
```

My output:

```
12.0+8.0
8.0/5.0
5.0-4.0
```

I am able to attach the operators to the numbers, but they won't evaluate.

Comment: Why should they evaluate?

Comment: I don't think so you can put "operator" dynamically at run-time just like how you're doing `op` and evaluate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work that way. You need to make the operator do its thing with your own code.

Example:

```
if(op.equals("+") ) {
    double result = numer1 + numer2;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With java 8 you can use nashorn

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Calculate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        String command = "1 / 2";
        ScriptEngineManager scriptManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        Object result = scriptEngine.eval(command);
        System.out.println("result " + result);
    }

}
```

In your cases (math operations) `result` could be an `Integer` or a `double`. But it could be something else in other cases.